# How do I get all the public properties and method from any .net class?

Tags: c#

i need to write simple application that get class name ( assume that the class appears in the application AppDomain ) and print to console

```
 all the public properties 
 values of each properties 
 all the method in the class
```

Comment: Have you looked at Type.GetProperties and Type.GetMethods? If so, where did you run into problems?

Comment: homework?  If so, tag it as such.  Regardless... what have you tried?  It seems like a quick search on "reflection" and ".net" would have answered your question.

Comment: i looked at Type.GetPropetries but how can i know what is the value that in the class instance on runtime when i know that the class is object and can't call the 'Get' value

Comment: @Yanshof: Did you look at the type *returned* by GetProperties, and follow it through? You've got to be able to do a bit of research...

Comment: you can just help if you want - i looked and i did not found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var p = GetProperties(obj);
var m = GetMethods(obj);
```

-

```
public Dictionary<string,object> GetProperties<T>(T obj)
{
    return typeof(T).GetProperties().ToDictionary(p=>p.Name,p=>p.GetValue(obj,null));
}

public MethodInfo[] GetMethods<T>(T obj)
{
    return typeof(T).GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can get it by using `GetValue` method of `PropertyInfo` object that you got by calling `GetProperties` method

```
foreach(PropertyInfo pi in myObj.GetType().GetProperties())
{
     var value = pi.GetValue(myObj , null);
}
```

`PropertyInfo` object contain many methods that retrieve the information you want about the perperty like name, is it readonly ..etc

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b05d59ty.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Here are the codes. .  .

```
void Main()
{

    Yanshoff y = new Yanshoff();
    y.MyValue = "this is my value!";

    y.GetType().GetProperties().ToList().ForEach(prop=>
    {
        var val = prop.GetValue(y, null);

        System.Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", prop.Name, val);
    });

    y.GetType().GetMethods().ToList().ForEach(meth=>
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(meth.Name);
    });

}

// Define other methods and classes here

public class Yanshoff
{
    public string MyValue {get; set;}

    public void MyMethod()
    {
         System.Console.WriteLine("I'm a Method!");
    }


}
```